# Odoo show notification

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm looking to develop a module for odoo which will add a button to synchronize some data with an external feed. I've managed to get the basic behavior up and running, but ideally, I would like to show a notification when the (long-running) process starts/finishes.

The basic premise is that I have this ListController and from there I'm trying to figure out how to show a notification. Like when you browse to a different view there is this `Loading` on the top.

Looking at the github respository there seems to be a `NotificationManager` which is instantiated by `AbstractWebClient`. And from the odoo javascript presentation  they talked about `trigger_up` to propegate calls upwards. The display_notification was in their presentation as an example- but for some reason it does nothing.

Can anybody give me some pointers in the right direction how can i get the notification to work?

```
odoo.define('test.sync', function (require) {

"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var rpc = require('web.rpc');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');

var ListController = require('web.ListController');

    ListController.include({

        renderButtons: function($node) {

        this._super.apply(this, arguments);

            if (this.$buttons) {

                let filter_button = this.$buttons.find('.sync_button');

                filter_button && filter_button.click(this.proxy('do_sync')) ;

            }

        },

        do_sync: function () {

            this.trigger_up('display_notification', {        title: 'Move Zig',        message: 'All your bases are belong to us'   });         

        }

    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the controller, or the renderer just write this:

```
this.do_notify('title', 'message :)');
```

[image]

See the documentation [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#notifications).
Basically the do_notify and do_warn methods are defined in the ServiceMixin class, which is inherited by the abstract controller and renderer by default ::I think::

Comment: Thanks! The class hierarchy is quite confusing when just reading from the source code.  Ultimately I ended up finding a better way to handle the 'notifications' I originally intended by incrementing/decrementing the 'loading' reference counter.

Answer (score 1):

For version 16 you have to use notification service,

```
// in setup
this.notificationService = useService("notification");
this.actionService = useService("action");

// later
this.notificationService.add("You closed a deal!", {
  title: "Congrats",
  type: "success",
  buttons: [
      {
          name: "See your Commission",
          onClick: () => {
              this.actionService.doAction("commission_action");
          },
      },
  ],
});
```

reference [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/frontend/services.html#notification-service)